# How to find an element in deeply nested data structure?

Tags: clojure, tree-traversal

I have this structure (which it is the result of parsing JSON response):

```
 [{"a" {"b" 1 "c" 2} 
       "children" [{"a" {"b" 3 "c" 4} "children" []}]}
  {"a" {"b" 5 "c" 6} "children" []}
  {"a" {"b" 7 "c" 8}
        "children" [{"a" {"b" 9 "c" 10} "children" []}]}]
```

So it is a tree. `children` is a vector of node. Each node is a map that has `a, b and children`.

I'm trying to find the node that has the value `9` for its `b` property.
So, the result of the lookup is:

I tried to traverse the structure with `tree-seq`:

```
(tree-seq #(not-empty? % "children") identity structure)
```

But actually I'm getting the same structure. I was expecting to get a sequence of nodes where the relation is flattened and then I can filter on the sequence.

How to do that in an idiomatic way (and hopefully performant)? Feel free to blow my mind with zippers or walk.

Comment: you want to search through current three nodes or in nested nodes as well? And the result should be either parent node (with children node)  either some of children node?

Comment: @fl00r I need to search through the nested nodes also. So, if I'm searching for the node where b = 9 , I want to get that node, including its children.

Comment: `(tree-seq #(or (vector? %) (% "children")) #(if (vector? %) (seq %) (% "children")) data)`?

Comment: @fl00r That is neat! Would you please post it as answer? And would you please explain why `vector?` is part of if-branch predicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired tree-seq like so:

```
(def ts (mapcat (partial tree-seq #(contains? % "children") 
                                  #(get % "children"))
                your-data-structure))
```

`mapcat` is required because your input datastructure contains multiple root-nodes.

E. g. find a node like so:

```
(first (filter #(= (get-in % ["a" "b"]) 9) ts))
;-> {"a" {"b" 9, "c" 10}, "children" []}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(def data
  [{"a" {"b" 1 "c" 2} 
    "children" [{"a" {"b" 3 "c" 4} "children" []}]}
   {"a" {"b" 5 "c" 6} 
    "children" []}
   {"a" {"b" 7 "c" 8}
    "children" [{"a" {"b" 9 "c" 10} "children" []}]}])
```

`branch?` fn will receive whole vector as an argument on first iteration, so I used `vector?` predicate, but it is unnecessary because we could simplify it with simple `not-empty` function which will work perfectly fine for both vector and map.

```
(tree-seq 
  not-empty
  #(if (vector? %) % (% "children")) 
  data)
```

Comment: Performance: branch? is supposed to be a predicate. Reliability: Logical truth is not even mentioned in the docstring of tree-seq. Performance: The vector? condition only holds one time. Style: #(not-empty %) is the same as not-empty.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin What do you mean by: `"vector? condition only holds one time"` ?

Comment: @Chiron The only vector passed to that lambda is the input dataset. From thereon, all children are maps. This is because the input dataset is not a generic node. It is a collection of children (or root-nodes, depending on how you want to see it).